# Creating a Curved and Straight Platform

Tags: modeling

A bit of a blender noob here. I'm trying to make a straight platform that curves around a cylindrical structure.

I've added photos for reference, so hopefully what I'm trying to do makes sense!

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

[image]

[image]

Currently using Blender 3.4.1

Comment: If you select an edge and Ctrl E > Offset Edges, you can create an extrude or an offset edge, I'm not sure it answers though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you need your model to be manifold, with a continuous surface enclosing a single volume, like the following example, but the method could be adapted.

Rather than attempting to stretch the the inner shelf *to* the enclosing profiles, one way or another, you can construct the shelf *from* the profiles. This variation also assumes the topology has been thought ahead:

[image]

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> loops cut in the receiving surfaces. They can be <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> snapped to the same height. (In another variation, these could be <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicated out, to make separate elements, and /or converted to curves, resampled for matching vertex-counts).
- The loops are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevelled to a depth
- ..and the desired portions selected.

[image]

- For a sub-div manifold, the selection can be
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> inverted, and the remainder <kbd>I</kbd>
  inset, to isolate the shelf from the surrounding curvature
- Once isolated, (if necessary,) the original selection can be connected with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Bridge Edge Loops
- .. and further loops cut in, for a more even distribution of faces.

This variation will subdivide well, if that's the way you're going. But the main point is, one way or another, to steal the curves from the existing geometry.